# Calculating range of float in C

Tags: c, floating-point

Title pretty much sums it all.

I know that floats are 32bit total with 23bits for mantissa and 8bits for the exponent value and 1 for signing.

Calculating the range of "int" is pretty simple:  32bits = 32-1bit signature =31bits ==>  Range is therefore 2³¹= 2.14e9

The formula makes sense...

Now i've looked around stackoverflow but all the answers i've found regarding float range calculations lacked substance. Just a bunch of numbers appearing randomly in the responses and magically reaching the 3.4e38 conclusion.

I'm looking for an answer from someone with real knowledge of subject. Someone that can explain through the use of a formula how this range is calculated.

Thank you all.

Mo.

Comment: [Try this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: " know that floats are 32bit total ..." You know wrong. Even for the type `float` this is not necessarily true. The C standard does not enforce a specific format or size, just minimum requirements. And for `double` that is definitively wrong. For `int` you are also wrong. Most systems actually use 16 bit `int`s.

Comment: Please @Olaf educate me then... if you have a positive contribution i'm all ears. 

FYI i never mentioned double so it should not even be a consideration here.

Comment: *"8bits for the signing and exponent value"* ~ wrong! A 32-bit `float` has 8 bits exponent and 1 bit sign. The matissa has 24 bits significance but since it is normalised to have a `1` in its msb (except for the value `0`), that bit is not stored, only 23 bits of the 24 bit mantissa are stored .

Comment: Note the usage of markup to differentiate between floats (short for "floating point values") and `float` which is the C datatype. The former includes `double` (and `long double`), too. Anyway, SO is not the place for tutoring. Feel free to read the standard. Also there is this internet-thing you can find all information. There is more to programming than PCs.

Comment: Thanks for actually explaining that @WeatherVane.

Comment: Check the header `float.h` for characteristics of floating-point types for your implementation (`FLT_MIN`, `FLT_MAX`, `DBL_MIN`, `DBL_MAX`, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C does not define `float` as described by OP.  The one suggested by OP: [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32), the most popular, is one of many conforming formats.

What C does define

**5.2.4.2.2 Characteristics of floating types**

```
s sign (±1)
b base or radix of exponent representation (an integer > 1)
e exponent (an integer between a minimum emin and a maximum emax)
p precision (the number of base-b digits in the significand)
fk nonnegative integers less than b (the significand digits)

x = s*power(b,e)*Σ(k=1, p, f[k]*power(b,-k))
```

For binary32, the max value is

```
x = (+1)*power(2, 128)*(0.1111111111 1111111111 1111 binary)

x = 3.402...e+38
```

---

Given 32-bits to define a `float` many other possibilities occur.  Example: A `float` could exist just like binary32, yet not support infinity/not-a-number.  The leaves another exponent available numbers.  The max value is then `2*3.402...e+38`.

---

binary32 describes its significand ranging up to 1.11111... binary.  The C characteristic formula above ranges up to 0.111111...

Comment: Isn't that `1.1111111111 1111111111 111`? The highest bit of the mantissa is an implied 1. Your version only gives `1.701e+38`.

Comment: @Weather Vane Amended answer.  The `emax` of the formula is `Emax + 1` from [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding).   Note: C's significand starts with `power(base, -1)`.  Same value - just different ways to express it.

Comment: Well, that link says `Emax = FEH−7FH = 127`

Comment: @Weather Yes `Emax` on the linked page is 127.  But `Emax` is not the same as `emax` as used in the C standard - there is a difference of 1.  The C standard uses a specification where the largest `Σ` of digits (significand)  would be just less than 1.

Comment: @chux i'm still not getting the 3.402e+38.
I tried recalculating using 

(1)*(2¹²⁸)*(0.8388607) = 2.85e+38

0.8388607 being the binary equivalent of 1111111111 1111111111 1111. 

Any idea whats going wrong?

Comment: @DuckSauce binary `0.111111111111111` is very nearly `1`, in the same way that decimal `0.9999999` is very nearly `1`.

Comment: Well i guess we have a winner. Thanks @chux for the solid input!

Answer (score 0):

C uses single-precision floating point notation, which means that a 32-bit float has 1 bit for the sign, 8 bits for the exponent, and 23 bits for the mantissa. The mantissa is calculated by summing each mantissa bit * 2^(- (bit_index)). The exponent is calculated by converting the 8 bit binary number to a decimal and subtracting 127 (thus you can have negative exponents as well), and the sign bit indicates whether or not is negative. The formula is thus:

```
(-1)^S * 1.M * 2^(E - 127)
```

Where S is the sign, M is the mantissa, and E is the exponent. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format for a better mathematical explanation.

To explicitly answer your question, that means for a 32 bit float, the largest value is `(-1)^0 * 1.99999988079071044921875 * 2^128`, which is `6.8056469327705771962340836696903385088 × 10^38` according to  Wolfram. The smallest value is the negative of that.